# How to Pass an Object to client Javascript - NodeJS & express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, client, handlebars.js

I'm having a little bit problems, I'm trying to send an object to use on my Javascript client side, whenever I render the view. I am sending it this way (Im using Handlebars)

```
  > locations=[ {
    >               local:"my_local",                    
    >                desc:"myDesc"                  
    >               }]; 

res.render('myView', { locaciones:locaciones });
```

// Then in my view Inside a script tag i try to get that var and print it

```
<script>
  var myObj='{{locations}}';
   console.log(locations);
</script>
```

the result is this :

```
[object]
```

and I can't use any property of it because it's undefined

Comment: Try console.log(locations.local);

Comment: @s007 the result is "undefined"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send your object as a string.

Like `locations = JSON.stringify({local:"my_local",desc:"myDesc"});`

And on client side you can parse it to get an Object

Like  `loc = JSON.parse(locations);`

Now you can use loc as Object.

Comment: I'm getting this error when i try to parse " SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data "

Comment: the problem was that JSON.stringify changed the quotes for &quote so I couldn't parse it on the client side. I fixed it with this : loc=JSON.parse(locations.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'))

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but in case others are looking for an easy way to pass an object from the server to the client in nodejs here's how I do it.

On the server I do something like:

```
res.render('my_page',{'my_object': my_object});
```

Then on the client side in my jade I'd do:

```
-var name = my_object.name;
```

(assuming there's a "name" property in my_object)

Then just use it however you need it.

Like:

```
p Hello #{name}
```